# Xcode gives error: property 'window' not found on object of type AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm trying to make a Mac app by following a tutorial but Xcode comes up with the error property 'window' not found on object of type AppDelegate.

My code is

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#include "MasterViewController.h"

@interface  AppDelegate()
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet MasterViewController *masterViewController;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // 1. Create the master View Controller
    self.masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

    // 2. Add the view controller to the Window's content view
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.masterViewController.view];
    self.masterViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

I don't know what this means or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Under @interface try adding:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
```

The error suggestions you haven't set the `property` for your window.

Comment: It says build successful and opens the window when I run it, but then the rainbow-colour wheel starts and I have to force quit the window.

Comment: That issue you just mentioned is completely different than this one. One thing you might check is to make sure you linked the window to the `AppDelegate Object` in Interface Builder.

Comment: Click on App Delegate Object and Select Connections Inspector and see if they are linked.

Comment: Where is the app delegate object? I have no experience with Xcode before.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time to teach someone how to use XCode. I would recommend you pick up a book on it, take a class, or get more familiar with the functionality before diving into the unknown.

Answer (score 0):

When create a project, uncheck the option "Use Storyboards".  XCode will create a "window" property for you. See [uncheck "Use Storyboards"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffx08.png).